# Docker entrypoint.sh not found

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

Following the instructions as [outlined](https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper/tree/main/auditor) to deploy Duo CloudMapper to AWS environment and getting an error

Docker File

```
FROM python:3.7-slim as cloudmapper

LABEL maintainer="https://github.com/0xdabbad00/"
LABEL Project="https://github.com/duo-labs/cloudmapper"

WORKDIR /opt/cloudmapper
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1 

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential autoconf automake libtool python3.7-dev python3-tk jq awscli

COPY cloudmapper/. /opt/cloudmapper
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/cloudmapper/entrypoint.sh

# Remove the demo data
RUN rm -rf /opt/cloudmapper/account-data/demo

# Install the python libraries needed for CloudMapper
RUN cd /opt/cloudmapper && pip install -r requirements.txt


ENTRYPOINT /opt/cloudmapper/entrypoint.sh
```

Now building the docker image

```
C:\> docker build -t cloudmapper .
```

When I run the docker using the below command I get an error

```
C:/> docker run -t cloudmapper
```

Error

`/bin/sh: 1: /opt/cloudmapper/entrypoint.sh: not found`

Verified that the file exists in the appropriate location [image: screenshot attached]

Using Docker on Windows 10

Image in the dockerfile is python:3.7-slim

Comment: What are the image files you attached to the question?  Can you edit the question to include the source code necessary to demonstrate the problem (in the question itself, not behind a link) and the error you're getting (as text, not an image)?

Comment: @DavidMaze : I have updated the question to have more details within the question.

Comment: Is the script executable?  What is its very first line (usually, something like `#!/bin/sh`)?  Does it have Unix or DOS line endings?

Comment: It had the windows line endings. Once I replaced them with Unix line endings its all working now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the images are removed and replaced with text and the question doesn't get closed.

bash can return "file not found" when

- the entrypoint shell script is not marked executable for the current user
- the hash bang in the entrypoint shell script points to a binary that does not exist
- the shell script actually does not exist.

You can fix the first problem by ensuring you use the new --chmod flag to ensure the executable bit is set. Even if the user is `root` it is necessary that there is at least 1 executable bit set.

```
COPY --chmod=0755 *.sh /opt/cloudmapper/
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/cloudmapper/entrypoint.sh"]
```

ps. This integrated COPY --chmod only works with buildkit enabled builds, so you might need to force buildkit, or split the chmod into a separate explicit `RUN` step.

The 2nd issue can be dealt with by ensuring the first line of `entrypoint.sh` uses sh rather than bash if you are using a lightweight base image like alpine:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
# etc
```

Also, if on Windows especially, ensure ALL files, especially the entrypoint .sh file, are set to utf-8 encoding with lf style line endings. As linux doesn't understand the cr, it will try to execute `/bin/sh<cr>` as the shell which clearly doesn't exist.

In terms of the file not existing, verify the entrypoint.sh is being copied into a location that is referenced by env.PATH, or that the entry point directive uses a fully qualified path.

--
edited to add cr-lf revelation.

Comment: After updating the docker file with the permissions, I get the error : standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Comment: one thing to try, if scripts won't execute, is to set the entrypoint to a shell and execute them: `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/opt/cloudmapper/entrypoint.sh" ]`

Comment: Had to update the CRLF to LF in the .sh file and it works.Thanks for the help

Comment: windows line endings ftw

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had an error:

```
> [27/35] RUN /entrypoint.sh:
#31 0.503 /bin/sh: 1: /entrypoint.sh: not found
```

I just run dos2unix command and the issue gone:

```
dos2unix entrypoint.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

*Problem Solved*

**For Windows Users, just convert CRLF to LF for entrypoint.sh file**

Then run the docker container

[image]